# como iniciar app inventor en ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu

yo tengo ubuntu version 14.04 y no se como iniciar app inventor 2 ya esta todo instalado lo que quiero saber es como iniciar AIstarter pa'ra poder usar app inventor porfavor me podrian ayudar?

Translation:

> I have Ubuntu version 14.04 and App Inventor 2 isn't starting yet it
>   is   already installed. How do I start it?

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que ir [aquí](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/) Entrar con sus detalles . Para un proyecto de ejemplo , vaya [aquí](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/hellopurr.html).